# read_html is creating a dataframe with 2x's the number of columns

Tags: pandas, io

I created a dataframe some data from a site.

```
df = pd.read_html('http://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?tc=1', header = 0)[4].set_index('Date')
```

I then created an html file with the name of the html file as the date.

```
     today_date = dt.date.today().isoformat()
    html_name = 'Insider Trading/{}_buys.html'.format(today_date)
    df.to_html(html_name)
```

The html file looks something like this when I open it(but has borders around rows and columns). Very clean and no mistakes.

```
        Ticker                         Owner    Relationship    Transaction     Cost    #Shares     Value ($)   #Shares Total   SEC Form 4
Date                                    
Sep 30  PIH     Fundamental Global Investors,       10% Owner          Buy       6.25        700         4375         352202    Sep 30 06:28 PM
Sep 28  PIH     Fundamental Global Investors,       10% Owner          Buy       6.05       36400       220220        351502    Sep 30 06:28 PM
Sep 30  FSTR                     Vizi Bradley        Director          Buy      12.00       14419       173028        801209    Sep 30 05:21 PM
Sep 29  FSTR                     Vizi Bradley        Director          Buy      12.00       11292       135504        786790    Sep 30 05:21 PM
Sep 28  FSTR                   Vizi Bradley          Director          Buy      11.83        9500       112385        775498    Sep 30 05:21 PM
```

Now when I try to read the html file back to a dataframe like via code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_html('Insider Trading/2016-09-30_buys.html')[0]
```

(There is only one dataframe when I read the html, so that's why I'm using[0])

I'm getting double the amount of columns,  20  instead of 10 columns, and those 10 extra columns have 'Unnamed 1' type of names.

So my output is coming out something like this:

```
  Unnamed: 0 Ticker                          Owner Relationship  Transaction  \
0     Sep 30    PIH  Fundamental Global Investors,    10% Owner         Buy   
1     Sep 28    PIH  Fundamental Global Investors,    10% Owner         Buy   
2     Sep 30   FSTR                   Vizi Bradley     Director         Buy   
3     Sep 29   FSTR                   Vizi Bradley     Director         Buy   
4     Sep 28   FSTR                   Vizi Bradley     Director         Buy   

    Cost  #Shares  Value ($)  #Shares Total       SEC Form 4  Date  \
0   6.25      700       4375         352202  Sep 30 06:28 PM   NaN   
1   6.05    36400     220220         351502  Sep 30 06:28 PM   NaN   
2  12.00    14419     173028         801209  Sep 30 05:21 PM   NaN   
3  12.00    11292     135504         786790  Sep 30 05:21 PM   NaN   
4  11.83     9500     112385         775498  Sep 30 05:21 PM   NaN   

   Unnamed: 11  Unnamed: 12  Unnamed: 13  Unnamed: 14  Unnamed: 15  \
0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
2          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
3          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
4          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   

   Unnamed: 16  Unnamed: 17  Unnamed: 18  Unnamed: 19  
0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
1          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
2          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
3          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  
4          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

What could I  be doing wrong?

I also tried this code based on a suggestion:

```
df = pd.read_html('http://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?tc=1', header = 0, attrs = {'class': 'body-table'})[0].set_index('SEC Form 4')
```

but seem to run into the same problem.

Comment: If you look at the source of that page, you will find it has tables nested in tables, nested in tables. Without doing much more digging, I would suspect it is due to that. You could simply exclude those columns where all values are null.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought I was making some silly coding mistake.

Comment: You may also be able to get the data more "clean" initially by specifying an attribute. For example, `attrs = {'class': 'body-table'}`, which appears to be the table you are trying to read.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out that now.. What's strange is when I first read the html page to a pandas dataframe, the dataframe is clean. However, after converting it to an html file, and then trying to read the html file back into a dataframe, I get this mess.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same problem even when I add attrs = {'class': 'body-table'}. I will update the question.